# Preloader covering page with an invisible layer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a preloader which works fine apart from when it is gone it is still there as a invisible layer covering all the content on the page. So none of the content like links can be clicked. How can this be solved but still keep the animation?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Reece_Dev/pen/QvWeEz)

```
<body>
  <div id="preloader_wrap">
    <div class="section" id="right_sect">

    </div>

    <div class="section" id="left_sect">

    </div>

    <div id="content">
      <div id="img">

      </div>

      <div id="loading_bar">
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <header>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</body>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

css:

```
*{
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}

body{
  background-color: #666666;
  width: 100%;
}

#preloader_wrap{
  z-index: 1010;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.section{
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%; 
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  top: 0;
  transition: width 1s;
}

#left_sect{
  left: 0;
}

#right_sect{
  right: 0;
}

#content{
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  transition: all 1s;
}

#img{
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#loading_bar{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

#loading_bar div{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: spin 0.9s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 0.9s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 0.9s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin 0.9s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0%  {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}   
}

body.loaded .section{
  width: 0;
}

body.loaded #content{
  opacity: 0;
}

header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 300px;
}

ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 40px;
}

ul li a{
  color: white;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('body').addClass('loaded');
    }, 2000);

});
```

Comment: you need to do something about the z-index of your wrapper, set it to 0 after loading completes

Comment: try add `$("#preloader_wrap").css("z-index","-1")` after ` $('body').addClass('loaded');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your script to this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('body').addClass('loaded');
        $('#preloader_wrap').remove();
    }, 2000);

});
```

That will completely remove the layer once the page is loaded.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen - Thanks for the edit.  I am literally only just having my first coffee of the day :p

Comment: But this will remove all the elements with in the preloader_wrap.. And according to his html there are a lot of divs inside it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help. But your solution doesn't work for me. As the two halves of the preloader no longer animate have a look at my codepen if you don't understand me

Comment: @SahilDhir They all wrap around a loading bar div.  Sounds like preloader content to me.

Comment: @SahilDhir "this will remove all the elements with in the preloader_wrap". yes, that's the whole point. At the moment, the wrap is getting in the way. And once the content is loaded, it isn't needed.

Comment: @Reece You should move everything out of the preloader that isn't actually part of it.  That way you can remove it when the page is loaded.  You should only need to move the sections and header out.

Answer (score 0):

Your loader area has a z-index of 1010, which puts it in front of everything else, and you aren't removing that, or removing the element itself. And because its width and height are 100% it blocks the whole page.

You can fix this just using CSS. You're already doing this:

```
body.loaded .section{
  width:0;
}

body.loaded #content{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

However, this only hides the inner parts of the loader, not the whole thing. Do this instead:

```
body.loaded #preloader_wrap {
  display:none;
}
```

See working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZKbJEj

Answer (score 0):

Its basically a **z-index problem on preloader_wrap**. **You can fix the z-index after the loader is loaded** with `$("#preloader_wrap").css("z-index","-1")`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').addClass('loaded');
    $("#preloader_wrap").css("z-index", "-1");
  }, 2000);


});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #666666;
  width: 100%;
}

#preloader_wrap {
  z-index: 1010;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.section {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  top: 0;
  transition: width 1s;
}

#left_sect {
  left: 0;
}

#right_sect {
  right: 0;
}

#content {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  transition: all 1s;
}

#img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#loading_bar {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

#loading_bar div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: spin 0.9s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 0.9s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 0.9s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin 0.9s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

body.loaded .section {
  width: 0;
}

body.loaded #content {
  opacity: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 300px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 40px;
}

ul li a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="preloader_wrap">
    <div class="section" id="right_sect">
      sdsadsadsa
    </div>

    <div class="section" id="left_sect">
      dasdsadsad
    </div>

    <div id="content">
      <div id="img">

      </div>

      <div id="loading_bar">
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <header>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not overly clear on which parts of your markup you are trying to hide, but assuming it's all of the stuff within the preloader_wrap element (and if not I would move that markup outside of it), the issue you are having is that this element is stacked on top of the other elements due to it's z-index being higher.

The easiest fix for this is to add the following CSS:

```
body.loaded #preloader_wrap {
  display: none;
}
```

I can see that this breaks your animation, you could consider the following instead:

```
body.loaded #content{
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

However this feels like a bit of a hack given we wouldn't be hiding the wrapper here therefore if anything else in it gave it height it would still overlay part of the page.

I would consider refactoring your markup/CSS transition to make this work for you in a more consistent way.